# Referencing equations in latex

Tags: equations, cross-referencing

I am trying to reference equations in latex (I am writing in overleaf) and am using the code as in the [official overleaf documentation](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions/How_to_include_and_reference_equations) i.e.

```
\begin{equation}\label{Emc2}
E=mc^2
\end{equation}

Einstein wrote his famous equation \ref{Emc2}, blah blah blah ....
```

However on compiling, the reference just shows as a pure number i.e.

> Einstein wrote his famous equation 1, blah blah blah ....

whereas I would like the number reference in parentheses, as it is in most academic papers

> Einstein wrote his famous equation (1), blah blah blah ....

I am surprised that I haven't been able to find documentation for this.

EDIT:
As requested, I am putting in more complete source code. I am writing in several files and have a control file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{a4wide}

\title{   }
\author{   }
\date{April 2019}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\subfile{introduction.tex}
\subfile{math.tex}
\subfile{1.tex}
\subfile{2.tex}
\subfile{3.tex}
\subfile{4.tex}
\subfile{5.tex}

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{ref.bib}

\end{document}
```

And an example of where I am putting in the equation and reference

```
\documentclass[1.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}

\section{.....}

..text..

\begin{equation}\label{PLT}
Z(\lambda) = \int_{\mathcal{C_x}} dz g(z) e^{-\frac{f(x)}{\lambda}}
\end{equation}

..text..

iv) The exact value of the integral \eref{PLT} is then given by...
```

Which shows up as

> The exact value of the integral PLT is then given by...

Note that when I am compiling, I am doing so from my control file. All of the citations come out fine in squared brackets, and the references work when using \ref, but not when using \eref

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SE! Replace `\ref` by `\eqref`.

Comment: please test the code examples you post, `\label{Emc2}`... `\ref{Emc^2}` would not have produced any cross reference, it is always best to post a complete small document so that people can reproduce the problem

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I apologise, that was a typo.

Comment: @marmot i'm afraid this didn;t work. Now all of my references just show up as plain text i.e. "equation \eref{Emc2} ..." shows up as "equation Emc2 ..." rather than the number in parentheses.

Comment: This is very surprising. Please provide a document that starts with `\documentclass`, ends with `\end{document}` and shows the behavior.

Comment: again, if you provided a _complete_ test document it would be clear why `\eqref` is acting in a non standard way.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle done!

Comment: @21joanna12 no sorry the posted code can not be used at all, it is neither complete (missing `\end{document}`  and references multiple files that are not generally available. If you want anyone to explain why `\eqref{foo}` is producing `equation foo` instead of `(1)` then you need to provide a file that reproduces that behaviour that people can run and trace.

Comment: oh sorry `but not when using \eref`  that presumably produces an _error_ about an undefined command, the command you want is `\eqref` with a q

Comment: @DavidCarlisle So do people writing several section documents not get assistance? I am not sure a practical way of including all of the files here, and I wouldn't want to include their content anyhow. I have included all of the structual code (I considered putting in the \end{document} in fact, but I thought it not relevant because my code wouldn't even be compiling at all if I didn't put it in, so it is obviously there. That is the only bit of structural code I had omitted.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That did it, thank you! Mindless omission. Glad I didn;t have to make my post longer with even more code.

Comment: @21joanna12 your code was already too long!! you should have made a small but complete example as in the one in AboAmmar's answer, but using `\eref` then the answer would have been clear without needing so many comments asking for clarification.

Comment: the purpose of the example is to allow _other_ people to reproduce the problem and test answers. so examples that omit required commands and reference unsupplied files make it harder for people to help you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have two options; either use `(\ref{..})` or `\eqref{..}` as noted out by @marmot in a comment. The latter requires adding `amsmath` in your preamble.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}   % <-- for \eqref
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{Emc2}
E=mc^2
\end{equation}

Einstein wrote his famous equation (\ref{Emc2}), blah blah blah ....

Einstein wrote his famous equation \eqref{Emc2}, blah blah blah ....

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I had included the usepackage{amsmath} in my control file and thought it would filter through to all of my subfiles. Is this not the case?

Answer (score 3):

There's also the `cleveref` package, and its `\cref/\Cref`  commands, which spares you having to type the name of the environment, and cooperates with `hyperref`;

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % <-- for \eqref
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[noabbrev, nameinlink]{cleveref} % to be loaded after hyperref

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{Emc2}
E=mc^2
\end{equation}

Einstein wrote his famous \cref{Emc2}, blah blah blah ....

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It doesn't seem clear to me to label equation (1) in black while referring  this label with a red character string. I've done some changes with overleaf.com, but I'm not able to label with a red (1). Could you help?

Comment: If you remove the option `[nameinlinks]`, only the equation number will be coloured (not the parentheses). I added this colour just for demonstrative purposes (it's the default colour).