# Referencing equations \[\] in LaTeX

Tags: equations, cross-referencing

To write equations online I use the `$$` notations, to do it offline I use `\[\]`. Having the code:

```tex
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Neque egestas congue quisque egestas diam in arcu cursus euismod.
 
\[((3+2) \times (4+(-2)))\]

Nisl vel pretium lectus quam id leo. Iaculis at erat pellentesque adipiscing commodo elit at imperdiet. 

Eget arcu dictum varius duis. Augue neque gravida in fermentum. Vitae purus faucibus ornare suspendisse sed nisi lacus sed.
```

I would like to refer several times to the equation in other parts of the text. I know I can use `equation` to reference easily, as specified [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/487434/referencing-equations-in-latex). Can I reference it using `\[\]` and not `equation`? Am I required to use `equation` for it? What is the use of the equations with `\[\]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\[` is an un-numbered equation, so has no equation number to `\label` or reference.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `\[` by `\begin{equation}\label{foo}` and `\]` by `\end{equation}`.